# Query SQL table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework, and I am trying to query one of my tables, and only return the data from one column. I have used this code:

```
using (var ctx = new TestEntities())
{
    var Pokemon = ctx.C__PokemonName
                     .SqlQuery("select pokemon from __pokemonname")
                     .ToList();

    foreach (var pokemonname in Pokemon)
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pokemonname));
}
```

This code throws an error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
>   HResult=0x8013193C
>   Message=The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'TestModel.C__PokemonName'. A member of the type, 'ID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
>
> Source=EntityFramework
>
> StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.GetMemberOrdinalFromReader(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmMember member, EdmType currentType, Dictionary`2 renameList)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.GetColumnMapsForType(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmType edmType, Dictionary`2 renameList)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndType(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmType edmType, EntitySet entitySet, Dictionary`2 renameList)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InternalTranslate[TElement](DbDataReader reader, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, EntitySet& entitySet, TypeUsage& edmType)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.b__68()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.b__67()
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at PokeForm.Form1..ctor() in F:\VS Projects\PokeForm\PokeForm\Form1.cs:line 28
>   at PokeForm.Program.Main() in F:\VS Projects\PokeForm\PokeForm\Program.cs:line 19

Comment: Why are you using `SqlQuery` instead of using EF how it was designed to work?

Comment: If you want, you can add your `__pokemonname` model class to question, so I can cross-check if my answer is correct and add some explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to `select *` (select all columns) is following:

```
using (var ctx = new TestEntities())
{
    var pokemonList = ctx.C__PokemonName.ToList();

    foreach (var pokemon in pokemonList)
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pokemon.pokemonname));
}
```

If you want to query only for single column, you should use i.e [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)-library with custom sql (`select pokemonname from __pokemonname`) or you can select one column with Linq [.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)-operation and projected anonymous type.

```
using (var ctx = new TestEntities())
{
    var pokemonNameList = ctx.C__PokemonName.Select(r => new { pokemonname = r.pokemonname }).ToList();

    foreach (var name in pokemonNameList)
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(name.pokemonname));
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to select ascending?

Comment: Yes you can select ascending also. Add: `.OrderBy(r=>r.pokemonname)` before `.ToList()`